# UI is being blocked by Performance counters

Tags: c#, winforms

so I have a button, a *panel* and a *usercontrol*, on a click of the button the *usercontrol* is being called and shown on the panel, the problem is that it takes around 4-5 seconds for the *usercontrol* to show due to performance counters.

the usercontrol contains a timer, the timer simply updates the two labels (to show cpu and ram usage)

```
private void UpdateUI_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        LabelCPU.Text = $"CPU : {(int)PerformanceCounterCPU.NextValue()}%";
        LabelMemory.Text = $"Memory : {(int)PerformanceCounterMemory.NextValue()}%";
    });
}
```

I tried everything but it just keeps on freezing.

the usercontrol contains this code:

```
private static UserControlLogs _instance;
public static UserControlLogs Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null || _instance.IsDisposed)
            _instance = new UserControlLogs();
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

the code of the button that calls the usercontrol:

```
if (!PanelMain.Controls.Contains(UserControls.UserControlLogs.Instance))
{
    PanelMain.Controls.Add(UserControls.UserControlLogs.Instance);
    uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    uc.BringToFront();
}
else
{
    uc.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're unconditionally spawning a new Task every tick. That must spawn a lot of Tasks!!! Maybe wait until the previous one is finished before starting a new one...

Comment: that's not the problem though, it freezes the moment i click the button, the timer is set to 4 seconds

Comment: @Ayate it might be, If there are so many Tasks, the UI Task might not get any time slot.

Comment: @IVSoftware yes, it's built in .net framework and LabelCPU and LabelMemory are two labels inside the usercontrol

Comment: @IVSoftware the sample you posted previously seemed to work a lot better (though the ui is still being blocked 1 time out of 10-15 for some reason. no idea why you deleted it though

Comment: What happens if you take out the Task.Run _and_ take out the `BeginInvoke`? The thing is, there are many different `Timer` classes but the one you're probably using right now is `System.Windows.Form.Timer` which has its Tick events on the main thread already. I understand why you want to have a Task to update the UI, but blocking the UI while you update the UI is unavoidable. If there's anything time-consuming about that (like a calculation etc.) then do the calculation on a `Task` and 'Invoke' only when the `Text` is updated.

Comment: @IVSoftware yes im using the Form.Timer, i originally had it without a task and BeingInvoke, it works decent but sometimes it's still being blocked (very rarely) that's what i mostly tried to fix, but it probably has to do with something else since it happens very rarely.

Comment: And when you say "blocked" is that the same as when you say it "freezes"? (Thx for the feedback 'm starting to understand this better.) Now I have to make a project and see if I can reproduce this :)

Comment: @IVSoftware exactly, the moment i click the button the ui is frozen for 3-4 seconds then when it's unfrozen the usercontrol appears on the panel, don't know if it has to do with how the usercontrol is being called

Comment: You say "on a click of the button the usercontrol is being called and shown on the panel". I could be helpful to have just a little more of your code, like the button click handler. Can you please edit your post and add just enough to understand the full context? Thx in advance!

Comment: @IVSoftware i edited the post, i added what the usercontrol contains and the button that calls the usercontrol.

Comment: This code throws an InvalidOperationException, it is not legal to update the Text property from a task.  You can't see these exceptions, they get swallowed by the Task class.  Other than that you'll notice that label doesn't paint itself, you can see them reported in the Output window.  Something else causes the UC to paint itself, no guess what that might be, then you'll see the label.  You'll have to do this without Task.Run().  If PerformanceCounter causes unacceptable delays (I've seen it reported before), then just stop using it.

Comment: @HansPassant you're right, i originally had it without a task but it kept freezing the ui sometimes (which is the problem i'm facing right now). probably the best option it to remove the performancecounter as you mentioned

Comment: @Ayate plz help me understand your code where you make the singleton `static UserControlLogs`. Why not just create to begin with and not show it until it's needed? Also: can you take a look at the code I posted on GitHub? I'm having no issues getting this outcome. Can you see anything different between what I'm doing and what you're doing? [Clone or Browse](https://github.com/IVSoftware/cpu_performance_net_framework.git).

Comment: @IVSoftware i checked the code, on my side it sometimes take a lot longer to show the ui (which is the problem i'm facing) the difference is that mine is freezing when i click the button while yours freezes (takes a long time to show) due to performancecounter starting with the form on startup

Comment: @IVSoftware i edited your code to match mine, i do not own a github so i uploaded it here : https://gofile.io/d/YISe8M
it freezes sometimes on the click of the button

Comment: Now that I understand that you were looking at a different parameter, there's little difference between the performance of your code and mine. Here's the version you uploaded, only I now change colors on the tick. [Screen Capture](https://youtu.be/vOZ7SMX32XY). I added this as an `alt` branch in the repo. I must say I'm wildly intrigued as to why it doesn't work on your machine. But it does on mine!

Comment: @IVSoftware here is on my side : https://streamable.com/iz7rb1
you can see i'm holding the form and moving it around after clicking the button but it's frozen, it moves afterwards after it unfreezes

Comment: Well, I'm certainly not going to let the COMPUTER win. Give me a moment please. Oh hey in the meantime try a static  `Stopwatch`  beginning at with the MainForm CTor and get elapsed times to the `OnHandleCreated` overrides for `Main Form` and `UserControlLogs` and Tick. Looking at your helpful vid, it would be nice to know WHERE the long delay is occurring exactly. The UserControl instantiation? The first read of the Performance Counters? etc.

Comment: Have you tried an async call on your counters ? It seems when you call them the first time it takes some time. Try this maybe : `private async void timerUpdateUI_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int tmpCPU;
            await Task.Run(() => {tmpCPU = (int)PerformanceCounterCPU.NextValue()});
            labelCPU.Text = $"CPU : {tmpCPU}%";
        }`

Comment: @IVSoftware i added a stopwatch but it's hard to test it out, i opened the form for at least 40 times and it did not freeze, sometimes it might freeze twice a row (it's very random).  Bisjob i tried async but it still freezes, seems like the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @IVSoftware so i have a stopwatch.Start(); above InitializeComponent() (inside the usercontrol), usercontrol OnHandleCreated stopwatch shows 0:00.254 when running normally and 0:04.434 when freezing, i also noticed that it's mostly freezing when the computer is a bit inactive (idle)

Comment: Can you please pull the latest commit on the `master` branch and see if any of this makes a difference over there?

Comment: @IVSoftware sadly it's still freezing, it happens almost every time when i leave the computer idle for a few minutes, when it's not idle it might not freeze at all

Comment: @IVSoftware https://pastebin.com/raw/CLtxjabi
there's almost 5 seconds difference between Initializing Performance Counters and Initialization complete. the system is not going into screensaver/locked state, it's just idle for a few minutes

Comment: REALLY IMPORTANT: Make sure that in `Exception Settings` you click on `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` so that it shows a '✔' instead of a  solid square. You could be missing an exception being thrown. ALSO: when you say "idle" Is the system actually going into the screensaver/locked state you mean? Is there any way you could copy-paste that debug window log and file-share it? P.S. pull ONE more time please now the stopwatch will show intervals heh heh.

Comment: @IVSoftware here are the results (of the new pull) : https://pastebin.com/raw/heFTdA8V
checking "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" will give an exception on "await Task.Delay(timeout, cts.Token);". 'A task was canceled.' but it happens even when it's not supposed to freeze the ui

Comment: My last and final idea is this: Since your vid seems to show the UI blocking while the performance counters initialize (_which the Debug log shows takes ~5 seconds_) go ahead and run that initialization on a Task as well. See the `OnVisibleChanged` edit in my answer. It also spins a wait cursor.  ALSO: You can search for and uncheck `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException` (that's my WDT cancellation and is expected) but leave everything else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on our conversation, even after applying various strategies you are still experiencing system freezes. The purpose of re-enabling this answer is to show all the things that have been tried so far. This way, if anyone else wants to take a crack at it they'll be able to cover new ground.

---

1. Override the `OnVisibleChanged` of the `UserControl` to initialize. *Start a Task to create PerformanceCounters on the first occurrence of Visible (spin a WaitCursor while it's taking place) and then start the timer.*

---

```
public partial class UserControlLogs : UserControl
{
    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
        if(Visible)
        {
            if(PerformanceCounterCPU == null)
            {
                Task.Run(()=>
                {
                    Parent?.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Parent.UseWaitCursor = true; });
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: Initializing Performance Counters");
                    UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Restart();
                    PerformanceCounterCPU = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
                    PerformanceCounterCommittedMemory = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "% Committed Bytes In Use");
                    PerformanceCounterAvailableMemory = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: Initialization complete");
                    UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Restart();
                    Parent?.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
                    {
                        Parent.UseWaitCursor = false;
                        timerUpdateUI.Enabled = true;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

2. Add a semaphore to block reentrancy. *If the Task hasn't had a chance to complete, this will avoid starting new ones and having them pile up.*
3. Make the acquisition of data separate from the updating of the UI. *The PerformanceCounters can be read on a background thread. Then just take the result and marshal it back onto the UI thread to display.*
4. Add `Stopwatch` to diagnose the exact lines that are causing bottlenecks.
   *Output the Elapsed intervals to the Debug window to monitor.*

---

```
public partial class UserControlLogs : UserControl
{
    public static Stopwatch Stopwatch { get; } = new Stopwatch();
    public UserControlLogs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timerUpdateUI.Enabled = false;
    }
    private PerformanceCounter PerformanceCounterCPU = null;
    private PerformanceCounter PerformanceCounterCommittedMemory = null;
    private PerformanceCounter PerformanceCounterAvailableMemory = null;

    SemaphoreSlim _noReentrancy = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    // Handler is now async
    private async void timerUpdateUI_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cpu = 0, committed = 0, available = 0;
        
        // Skip if task is still busy getting the Performance Counter from last time.
        if (_noReentrancy.Wait(0))
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var wdt = startWatchdog(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            try
            {
                _ = Task.Run(() => getPerformance());
                await wdt; 
                BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { updateUI(); });
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                _noReentrancy.Release();
            }

            void getPerformance()
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: Getting performance data");
                UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Restart();
                cpu = (int)PerformanceCounterCPU.NextValue();
                committed = (int)PerformanceCounterCommittedMemory.NextValue();
                available = (int)PerformanceCounterAvailableMemory.NextValue();
                cts.Cancel(); // Cancel the WDT
                Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: Performance data received");
                UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Restart();
            }
            void updateUI()
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: UI Updating");
                UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Restart();
                labelCPU.Text = $"{cpu}%";
                labelMemoryCommitted.Text = $"{committed}%";
                labelMemoryAvailable.Text = $"{available}%";

                _colorToggle = !_colorToggle;
                if(_colorToggle) BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
                else BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: UI Updated");
                UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Restart();
            }
            async Task startWatchdog(TimeSpan timeout)
            {
                try
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: Watchdog Started");
                    UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Restart();
                    await Task.Delay(timeout, cts.Token);
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: Watchdog Timed Out");
                    UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Restart();
                    throw new TimeoutException();
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException) 
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: Watchdog Cancelled");
                    UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Restart();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

5. Don't block the button click. Use a `BeginInvoke` to show the UserControl.

---

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Start();
        Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: MainForm CTor:");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonShowUC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Elapsed}: ShowUC Click:");
            UserControlLogs.Stopwatch.Restart();
            _instance.Show();
        });
    }
}
```